# Can't connect to PostgreSQL server from AKS

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've created an AKS cluster and Flexible PostgreSQL database.

The postgresql database is public, and I made firewall entry while setting up the DB to allow local connection from my IP - which worked fine.

When I then tried to connect from AKS, I was unable to - I was getting timeouts.

Eventually, I clicked the setting to allow access from everywhere on azure
[image]

That fixed the timeouts, and I can now connect, but I get a new error:
`no pg_hba.conf entry for host "**.**.***.203"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be more to the error than that.

Comment: @jjanes unfortunately thats it. Some people say this is an issue with whitelisting IPs, but I don't know the IP addresses of the AKS nodes

Comment: I don't see anyway for PostgreSQL to generate such a message which ends after the host.  It goes on to specify more info, user, database, and encryption status.  Maybe MS added some hack to strip off that information in their Azure offering.

Comment: @jjanes fixed it was lack of ssl

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi If issue resolved can you please post the answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a public PostgreSQL Flexible server, like I believe you are, then you can configure firewall rules for inbound traffic to the Postgre server.

The same is not available for the private Postgre server, as traffic is only allowed from the virtual network where the subnet of the Postgre server was created, through private DNS resolution.

For your public Postgre server, you can easily add a firewall rule to allow the AKS public IP to reach the DB server. Tested it and it's working. You can find the public IP in the managed cluster resource group (default name is MC_*), by searching for a resource type public IP (the name of the resource is randomly generated):

[image: Public IP resource]

[image: Public IP value]